# Limit at negative infinity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^6+8}}{4x^2+\sqrt{3x^4+1}}$$

I think the strategy is to divide the numerator and denominator by x^2. Help please. The textbook answer is $$\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Did you have any difficulty applying your strategy? If so, exactly what was your difficulty?

Comment: @user3290793,  The pattern in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954792/limit-to-infinity-question/954830#954830 should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2$, it may be easier to factor out the appropriate factors from the radical expressions:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^6+8}}{4x^2+\sqrt{3x^4+1}} & = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^6\big(1+\frac{8}{x^6}\big)}}{4x^2+\sqrt{x^4\big(3+\frac{1}{x^4}\big)}} \\ & = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^6}\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{8}{x^6}}}{4x^2+\sqrt{x^4}\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{x^4}}} \\ & = \frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{8}{x^6}}}{4x^2+x^2\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{x^4}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Take out the factor $x^2$ from numerator and denominator and then cancel them and then apply the limit.